# Initialize pointer receiver in pointer method Go

Tags: pointers, go, receiver

How can I initialize a pointer receiver with a pointer method?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func (p *Person) Born() {

    if nil == p {
        p = new(Person)
    }

}

func main() {

    var person *Person
    person.Born()
    if person == nil {
        fmt.Println("This person should be initialized. Why is that not the case?")
    }
    fmt.Println(person)
}
```

One would expect person to be initialized (zeroed) after calling .Born() method which is a pointer receiver. But that is not the case. Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: `var person *Person` doesn't make sense. `Person` is a struct.

Comment: @Gravy Sure it makes sense. It defines `person` as an uninitialized pointer to a `Person` struct. It's just not what the OP wants in this case.

Comment: `person` which has type `pointer to Person` is initialized with it's zero value - `nil`

Answer (score 19):

> One would expect person to be initialized (zeroed) after calling .Born() method which is a pointer receiver.

Calling a method on a receiver assumes that the receiver is already initialized.

So you need to initialize it:

```
var person *Person
person = &Person{}  // Sets the pointer to point to an empty Person{} struct
```

Or in a single statement:

```
var person = &Person{}
```

Or shorthand:

```
person := &Person{}
```

The reason your intended self-initialization is failing:

```
func (p *Person) Born() {
    if nil == p {
        p = new(Person)
    }
}
```

Is that your new assignment to `p` is scoped to the `Born()` function, so outside the function it has no effect.

Comment: Thank you very much Flimzy for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, `person` will not be initialized by method `Born`. Parameters are passed by value through the assignment of arguments to parameters.

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> The type of a method is the type of a function with the receiver as
>   first argument.
>
> ```
> type Point struct{ x, y float64 }
>
> func (p *Point) Scale(factor float64) {
>   p.x *= factor
>   p.y *= factor
> }
> ```
>
> For instance, the method `Scale` has type
>
> ```
> func(p *Point, factor float64)
> ```
>
> However, a function declared this way is not a method.
>
> In a function call, the function value and arguments are evaluated in
>   the usual order. After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call
>   are passed by value to the function and the called function begins
>   execution. The return parameters of the function are passed by value
>   back to the calling function when the function returns.

To illustrate, here are various forms of the `Born` method call. The scope of `p` is limited to the method or function call.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

// Method
func (p *Person) Born() {
    if nil == p {
        p = new(Person)
    }
}

// Method as function
func Born(p *Person) {
    if nil == p {
        p = new(Person)
    }
}

func main() {

    // Initial method call form
    {
        var person *Person
        person.Born()
        fmt.Println(person)
    }

    // Equivalent method call by value form
    {
        var person *Person
        {
            p := person
            p.Born()
        }
        fmt.Println(person)
    }

    // Equivalent method call as function call form
    {
        var person *Person
        {
            p := person
            Born(p)
        }
        fmt.Println(person)
    }

    // Equivalent method call as inline function form
    {
        var person *Person
        {
            p := person
            if nil == p {
                p = new(Person)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(person)
    }

}
```

Output:

```
<nil>
<nil>
<nil>
<nil>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need instead is "constructor" or "factory" function:

```
type Person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func NewPerson(name string) *Person {
    return &Person{
        name: name,
    }
}

person := NewPerson("John Doe")
```

Generally, it's advised to try to define your types in such a way
so that their so-called "zero value"—the value a variable of this
type gets when it's not explicitly initialized otherwise—is ready
to be used right away.
In your case, it's questionable whether the zero value for `Person` is
sensible because it will have `age` of 0, which is perfectly reasonable,
and `name` being an empty string, which may or may not be OK.

Comment: Thank you Kostix. My question was purely educational and I am aware that Factory pattern is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`NewPerson` function can initialize as a person, nor using Person struct and Born method to get a new Person.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Dob  time.Time
}

func NewPerson(name string, year, month, day int) *Person {
    return &Person{
        Name: name,
        Dob:  time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local),
    }
}

func (p *Person) GetAge() string {
    d := time.Since(p.Dob)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s's age is %d", p.Name, int(d.Hours()/24/365))
}

func (p *Person) Born() {
    p.Name = "New born (unnamed)"
    p.Dob = time.Now()
}

func main() {
    joe := NewPerson("Joe", 1999, 12, 31)
    joeAge := joe.GetAge()
    fmt.Println(joeAge)

    newPerson := &Person{}
    newPerson.Born()
    newPersonAge := newPerson.GetAge()
    fmt.Println(newPersonAge)
}
```